# How to change background of a sidebar?

Tags: css, google-drive-api, blogger

I'm trying to change a background of a sidebar like this:

```
.sidebar-container{
background-image:url('https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fvfiH8u8U1GePrBcbc7g8wtsD_nBbI1M');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

the change isn't kicking in. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to upload this image in another service? Try uploading the picture in a Google Photos shared folder and click with the left button, then in "Open this image in a new tab" and copy that URL.

Comment: Didn't work. And didn't work from Dropbox either. How people make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

[Web hosting in Google Drive deprecated](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) August 31, 2016.

You can upload the image file on Blogger in an unpublished post and copy image address.

If you want to use the Google Drive file anyway, change `open?` in the URL to `uc?`

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1fvfiH8u8U1GePrBcbc7g8wtsD_nBbI1M
```